# How Apache Geode/ Gemfire sysnchronous read or write to other data sources?

Tags: gemfire, geode

I found this picture from Internet, it is about Gemfire structure.
[image]

I am confused how does Gemfire synchronous read or write to other data sources?

I didn't find any learning materials about this.

Anyone who can tell me ?  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This synchronous / asynchronous reads and writes are done through `Events` and `Listeners`, which allows you to plugin your own application code into the architecture. As an example, the `CacheLoader` is the ideal example of a synchronous read. You can get more information about this from http://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/11/developing/events/chapter_overview.html.
Hope this helps.
Cheers.

Comment: Thank you. It helps me a lot.  But it's because I am still a bird programmer, could you please tell me where can I get a detail example ?

Comment: Hey @ShirleySun, did you have a look at [Cache Event Handler Examples](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/geode/developing/events/cache_event_handler_examples.html), [Implementing an AsyncEventListener for Write-Behind Cache Event Handling](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/11/developing/events/implementing_write_behind_event_handler.html) and [Implementing Cache Event Handlers](http://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/11/developing/events/implementing_cache_event_handlers.html)?. Are you looking for something more specific?.